# Does session is application based?

Tags: asp.net-core, session-cookies

We have two application A and B.

A - Asp.net core MVC

B - .Net core + Angular

User can navigate to B from A. while navigating from A to B, I need to pass the token to B.

can A application store the token in local storage and B (angular) can retrieve it and pass it B's APIs for every request?

or

Can A pass the token to B's API and B can store it in session. while loading B front end, it can make API call to retrieve the token from B's session and use it for other API calls?

or

can we use cookie to store the token?

which approch shold we use? any other best simple approch

Comment: You could easily pass tokens from client side, but if both are completely separated web sites the servers won't validate each other. You need to use some common authentication server that allows the same token to be used, be it a common database or a common microservice for handling logins.

Comment: Ok,  is there any way to pass atleast signed-in username from A to B?

Comment: Just as my above comment says you need to share some part of the backend, so that you can validate tokens cross-site. Passing username is insecure (they're publicly available information), you need authenticated tokens of some sort.

Comment: Do you want a single sign-on (SSO) experience, web apps within a site must share authentication cookies ?If so, you can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.